# CSS zoom effect background hover

Tags: css, background, hover

I am trying to archieve a zoom in my background's in divs. I don't want the div to be bigger, but I want the image to zoom on hover, without growing the div. I have tried everything, but I can't seem to get it to work.

CSS:

```
/* Theme  */
html {
margin-top: 0px !important;
}

/* DO NOT EDIT OR MONKEYS WILL BITE YOU */
.frame_holder {
position: absolute;
top: 8px;
bottom: 50px;
/* left: 50px; */
right: 150px;
background: #ffffff;
}

.my_frame {
width: 149%;
height: 108%;
/* border: 1px solid #e0e0e0; */
}

body {
    background-color: #f0ede9;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

}


.clearfix {
clear: both;
}

p {
font-family: Roboto;
padding: 1px;
}



#body.layout-1 {
background: #f0ede9 url(../images/border.gif) 640px top repeat-y scroll;
background-color: #f0ede9;
background-image: url(../images/border.gif), url(../images/border-2.gif);
background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat-y;
background-position: 640px top, 0px top;
}

a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #bababa;
font-family: Roboto;
}

#wrapper {
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
background: #2a2727;
margin-top: 20px;
color: #fff;
}

.top-logo-container {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url(http://favoritefm.com/wp-content/themes/FavClear/img/logo.png) 5% 50% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100px;
}



#main {
margin-left: 2px;
}

.presenter-ribbon {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #de1f26;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 20;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}

#presenter {
margin-top: 40px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.box-link {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 60px 20px 10px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .1s linear;
  -ms-transition: all .1s linear;
  -o-transition: all .1s linear;
}

.box-link .box-overlay {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2) inset;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all .2s linear;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear;
}

.box-link .box-overlay:hover {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2) inset;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all .2s linear;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear;
}

.box-link .box-visual {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  z-index: 5;
 max-width: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.box-link .box-visual:hover {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  z-index: 5;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
 opacity: 0.7;

}

.box-link h4 {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.box-link h4 {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 34px;
}

.presenter-one {
  display: block;
  height: 49.65%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
   -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all .2s linear;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear;
  }



    .presenter-two {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  width: 25%;

  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  }

    .presenter-three {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  width: 25%;

  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  }

      .presenter-four {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 25.4%;
  width: 25%;

  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  }

      .presenter-five {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 25.4%;
  width: 25%;

  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 737px) and (max-width: 1200px) {

    #wrapper {
    width: 100% 
    }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 737px) and (max-width: 1200px) {

    #wrapper {
    width: 100% 
    }

}



@media screen and (max-width: 736px) and (min-width: 415px) {

    #wrapper {
    width: 100% 
    }


#header {
width: 100%;
background: #2a2727;
color: #fff;
margin-top: 0px;
height: 100px;
}

.top-logo-container {
  display: block;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;

  background: url(http://favoritefm.com/wp-content/themes/FavClear/img/logo.png) 5% 50% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 120px;
}

#main {
margin-left: 2px;
}

#presenter {
margin-top: 40px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.presenter-one {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;

  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.presenter-two {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;

  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.presenter-three {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;

  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.presenter-four {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;

  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.presenter-five {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;

  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}



}


@media screen and (max-width: 414px) and (min-width: 1px) {

    #wrapper {
    width: 100% 
    }


#header {
width: 100%;
background: #2a2727;
color: #fff;
margin-top: 0px;
height: 100px;
}

.top-logo-container {
  display: block;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;

  background: url(http://favoritefm.com/wp-content/themes/FavClear/img/logo.png) 5% 50% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 120px;
}

#main {
margin-left: 2px;
}

#presenter {
margin-top: 40px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.presenter-one {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;

  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.presenter-two {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;

  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.presenter-three {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;

  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.presenter-four {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;

  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.presenter-five {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;

  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}



}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9b7fvfk6/

HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"><a href="" title="FavoriteFM" class="top-logo-container"></a></div>
<div id="main">
<div id="presenter">
<div class="presenter-one"><a class="presenter-ribbon" href="/Testcategorie" ng-if="element.ribon">Testcategorie</a><a class="box-link" href="/airfield"><h4 class="ng-binding">Dit is een testregel!</h4><span class="box-overlay"></span> <span class="box-visual" style="background-image: url('http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg')"></span></a></div>
<div class="presenter-two"><a class="presenter-ribbon" href="/Testcategorie" ng-if="element.ribon">Testcategorie</a><a class="box-link" href="/airfield"><h4 class="ng-binding">Dit is een testregel!</h4><span class="box-overlay"></span> <span class="box-visual" style="background-image: url('http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg')"></span></a></div>
<div class="presenter-three"><a class="presenter-ribbon" href="/Testcategorie" ng-if="element.ribon">Testcategorie</a><a class="box-link" href="/airfield"><h4 class="ng-binding">Dit is een testregel!</h4><span class="box-overlay"></span> <span class="box-visual" style="background-image: url('http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg')"></span></a></div>
<div class="presenter-four"><a class="presenter-ribbon" href="/Testcategorie" ng-if="element.ribon">Testcategorie</a><a class="box-link" href="/airfield"><h4 class="ng-binding">Dit is een testregel!</h4><span class="box-overlay"></span> <span class="box-visual" style="background-image: url('http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg')"></span></a></div>
<div class="presenter-five"><a class="presenter-ribbon" href="/Testcategorie" ng-if="element.ribon">Testcategorie</a><a class="box-link" href="/airfield"><h4 class="ng-binding">Dit is een testregel!</h4><span class="box-overlay"></span> <span class="box-visual" style="background-image: url('http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg')"></span></a></div>



</div>
</div>
```

Is there anyone who can help me? I thought I would have to make a box-visual:hover, but that's not doing anything either. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the hover to the `.box-link` should makes it working. Example:

```
.box-link:hover .box-visual {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

See [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9b7fvfk6/2/)

Comment: You're welcome :) Mark the answer as correct will be appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the image to cross the borders of the `div`, set the `div` CSS property to `overflow: hidden;`

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://goo.gl/1ex50e"/>
</div>
```